# How can use a variable value in histbase to plot area between 2 values in PINE SCRIPT?

Tags: pine-script

```
sma200 = sma(close,200)

base = close

plot(sma200, style=plot.style_area, histbase=base, color=sma200<base?color.green:color.red)
```

> Error: Cannot call 'plot' with 'histbase'=series[float]. The argument
> should be of type: input float

Comment: are you looking for area fill to fill in color between the close and the 200? Or are you looking to plot the difference between close and the 200 as a hist plot (columns).

Comment: Hi Bjorgum, that's it, i want plot area color between 2 values, in this case, fill to fill from sma200 to close price. I have the problem because the histbase is the value of the SMA but i can't find the correct format to convert it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sma200 = plot(sma(close,200))
base = plot(close)

conditionalColor = sma200<base?color.green:color.red
fill(sma200, base, conditionalColor)
```

Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

To create an area fill we must have either 2 plots, or 2 Hlines. We cannot however fill between an Hline and a plot. So we first plot our 200ma as we normally would, then we must create a second plot to to reference to fill between. In this case we want close, but we don't actually want to see that line. For this I used the color.new function setting transparency to 100 (invisible).  The fill functions first 2 arguments are the 2 plots we want to reference. We can do this by placing a variable before each plot (notice p1 and p2). Now we place those in the first 2 spots. I made a separate variable for your color argument calling it "col" so that we could use it for the line as well as the area fill.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)

sma200 = sma(close,200)

col = sma200<close ? color.green : color.red

p1 = plot(sma200, color=col)

p2 = plot(close, color=color.new(#FFFFFF, 100))

fill(p1,p2, color=col)
```

Cheers brother and best of luck with your coding and trading

Comment: Awesome!!! Thanks bro, 1 week trying to do this.